# Grafana - show all alerts connected to a specific channel

Tags: grafana, grafana-alerts

We are having a Grafana which is used by my entire company. I want to find all graphs which have an alert with a notification to my team. I know what is the notification channel but I don't know how to find the graphs.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Alerting Tab from left corner and click alert list

[image]

You will get the list of all alerts. On clicking the alerts it will take you to the graphs on which alerts are set.

Comment: Thanks, I knew about this tab. But this shows ALL alerts (~600 in my workplace) and I just want to find those that sends a notification to my team.